# List of users who signed-up last month, or last year

Tags: views

I want to get the number of users who signed-up the last month, or the last year.

Is there any module for achieving this? How can I do it using the Views module?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a View of Users. Group by signup date.

Comment: yes i created view thx.. i want to know the any exist module for this issue ?

Comment: I think I have no idea what you are asking. I don't think there is a module other than the Views module that creates lists of entities filterable by things like entity type, timestamps, etc.

Comment: ok i got  solution .. thx